# In AWS, does the whole VPC get a single DNS server or does each subnet in VPC gets a DNS server?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

This question is in the context of Private DNS hostnames.

In AWS, for each subnet in a VPC, the IP address of the DNS server is the base of the VPC network range plus two - Curious to understand

1. If it is a single DNS server for the entire VPC with interfaces in each subnet or
2. There are separate instances of DNS servers for each subnet

If there are separate instances of DNS servers for each subnet, how does the Private DNS name of an EC2 instance in a different subnet (within same VPC) gets resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one DNS server per VPC, and its private IP address is the base of the VPC network range plus two. [[ref](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html#vpc-sizing-ipv4)]

Comment: Thank you - As per AWS documentation, For example, in a subnet with CIDR block 10.0.0.0/24, one of the following five IP addresses that are reserved is: 
10.0.0.2: Reserved by AWS. - Is this not for DNS per subnet?

Comment: No, there are no additional DNS servers in each subnet. The `.2` IP (other than the one mentioned in my answer) for each subnet is reserved for future use only.